# Customize Oracle Access Manager

Tags: oracle, jsp, authentication, oracle11g

I would like to know how to change Oracle Access Manager's Login page.
I don't want to build a new custom page but only change a few UI components to the default Oracle page (like images and CSS).

The "login page" I'm talking about is: `console/login/LoginForm.jsp`, but I cannot find it on my server, does any one know where I can find this LoginForm.jsp??

I'm actually looking for the `login/LoginForm.jsp` in this [Oracle documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14571_01/web.1111/e13745/rebrand.htm#i1068655).

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

**Please note that I cannot install any additional programs on that server

Comment: Have you done the initial step of [expanding the look and feel template](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14571_01/web.1111/e13745/rebrand.htm#BABIJIJH)? Or does 'I cannot install...' mean you can't [deploy a console extension](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14571_01/web.1111/e13745/rebrand.htm#BABEDEGD) anyway?

Comment: Exactly, I cannot install Ant so I'm looking for an other way if any exists

Comment: Not sure I follow... you can build the `.war` file anywhere, you don't need `ant` on the server (though isn't it installed as part of this anyway?). You just need to be able to [copy it to the server and restart](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14571_01/web.1111/e13745/deploy.htm#g1076233). Clearly I'm missing something important *8-)

Comment: Ok thanks, i'll try to build it from somewhere else.

Comment: @AlexPoole I can't test right now, but I'm sure this will will work since I was able to build with ant and I got the LoginForm,jsp I was looking for! Thank you very much! I would like to give you the bounty, but it's my first time so how can I give it to you? Thanks again!

Comment: Glad to help. I've repeated the comments as an answer, which you can upvote, accept and [award the bounty to](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#bounty) as you see fit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to install any additional software on the server, you just need to be able to [copy a `WAR` file to the console extension directory](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14571_01/web.1111/e13745/deploy.htm).

You can build the `WAR` anywhere, that doesn't have to be done on the server. [Expand the look and feel template](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14571_01/web.1111/e13745/rebrand.htm#BABIJIJH), which will give you the `login/login.jsp` file you were looking for, make your changes, [build the archive](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14571_01/web.1111/e13745/rebrand.htm#BABEDEGD)  and [deploy](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14571_01/web.1111/e13745/deploy.htm) to your server.

Good luck!

Comment: thanks! i'll give you the bounty in 20h as the system wont take it now.